# WIX installer remove all the files when uninstalling from control panel

Tags: wix, uninstallation, wix3.5

i have created an MSi installer. when i install this installer it also installs a visual studio project which is actually a tutorial project. When user runs this project it generates `Bin` and `Obj` folders. when i uninstall the install it  does not delete all the those `Bin` and `Obj` folder which are generated after the installation.

Can you provide me some example how to use `RemoveFolder` tag in Wix to remove those two folders and the files inside them recursively.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RemoveFile will only remove files that are installed by this msi.
To remove entire folder you have to use util:RemoveFolderEx. To use it you have to:
- Store [TARGETDIR] in registry on install;
- Retrieve it on any actions except on install and store in local variable (using RegsitrySearch)
- Add util:RemoveFolderEx action to your main component and pass your stored path variable to the Property attribute.

If you need an example I could write it for you.